# How to add the Quantity field to Entity Reference views

Tags: commerce, entities

There is a problem with adding the "Quantity" field in views to Entity Reference.

When you add the Commerce Product:Quantity input field (from module Commerce Extra) - the field is added, but empty inside (in the back comment "form-item-add_to_cart_quantity--0", wrapped in span, and in the front is empty.

Need to "toppings" is not only mentioned, but also had the opportunity to change their quantity.
[image]